# Why did Maverick toss this character's dog tags into the sea?

Tags: plot-explanation, top-gun

In *Top Gun* (1986),

> Goose dies,

and Maverick throws his dog tags into the sea.

[image: animated GIF of Maverick throwing dog tags into the sea]

Maverick was fond of this character, so why would he throw their dog tags away?

Comment: In the [original script](https://assets.scriptslug.com/live/pdf/scripts/top-gun-1986.pdf) he throws away Goose's locker sticker. - *185. INT. THE READY ROOM-LATER. Maverick is alone. He is staring at a locker. TIGHT ON LOCKER- with Lt. Josh Bradshaw "GOOSE" written on tape. He reaches up and pulls it off slowly. [snip] 186. EXT. BOW OF THE SHIP-DAY He looks out, at the dying sun shimmering over the sea. **He takes Goose's name tape and stretches it out on the ship's railing. Then he starts out at one end and rolls it in a neat roll- throws it out to sea.***

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Maverick is honoring his friend. He died while on a ship, he's a sailor like the others on the ship, no matter what his job was. Maverick gave the sea the only thing he has left from him: Goose's ID tags. Goose wasn't buried at sea, with all due honors and rituals, so Maverick did his own ceremony. It is said that's also a way to soften the pain, a symbolic gesture of him letting go of the guilt he's felt over his friend's death. It can be both, as funeral are usually a way to do this: mourn, honor and move forward, as Maverick will do later when he goes back to flying with another RIO.

[Burial at sea](https://www.history.navy.mil/browse-by-topic/heritage/customs-and-traditions0/burial-at-sea.html) has long been a maritime tradition. From the [vikings](https://www.history.com/news/how-did-the-vikings-honor-their-dead)<sup>1</sup> burning the body on a ship to the Middle Ages where the body was sewn into a weighted shroud, usually sailcloth before being sunk into the sea, what was first a way to honor the dead along getting rid of a body you couldn't keep on board for sanitary reasons, has long become a way to just honor the departed.

> All other graveyards show symbols of distinction between great and small, rich and poor: but in the ocean cemetery, the king, the clown, the prince and the peasant are alike, undistinguishable. George Bruce, 1884, St Andrews.

More to read: [Burial at sea - Marine tradition](https://themaritimepost.com/2021/08/burial-at-sea-things-you-might-not-know/) - [Burial at Sea: A Time-Honored Tradition - Military](https://www.military.com/benefits/burial-and-memorial/burial-at-sea-a-time-honored-tradition.html)

> The [Spirit Boat Procession](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spirit_Boat_Procession) (精霊流し, Shōrō nagashi) is an event celebrated in various places in Japan. During the procession, people float boats which are said to be carrying the spirits of the deceased down the river.

NOTE: according to [Screenrant](https://screenrant.com/top-gun-movie-maverick-dogtags-viper-not-goose/) it might not be Goose's tags that Maverick is throwing into the sea, but that's another (intrepretation of the) story...

<sup>1. The ship burial is a viking funeral practice traditionally reserved for individuals of high honor. from [Norse funeral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norse_funeral)</sup>

Comment: Seems a little selfish though. He should have at least given the character’s family the opportunity to take custody of the dog tags if they wanted them (assuming the character had family—can’t remember)?

Comment: It's been discussed, some say they belonged to his son or wife.

Comment: In no version of the script I've read are the dog tags mentioned. When Maverick puts Goose's stuff in a box, there's a clock, book and other goods but no tags. He later gives the box to his wife.

Comment: It could also be a symbolic act of "letting it go" which is a bit of a trope in hollywood (like Rose threw the necklace at end of Titanic)

Comment: @RedBaron: I think I covered this with "*It is said that's also a way to soften the pain, a symbolic gesture of him letting go of the guilt he's felt over his friend's death.*" It's kind of common that the hero has to overcome a huge psychological hit before he can win, against himself *and* adversity.

Comment: Doesn't Goose die while they're still at Top Gun, i.e. not at sea?

Comment: They're from the Navy though